# Key entry simplification for the key-value pairs in a NSPasteboard property list

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am working with the property lists for the `NSPasteboard` object. The property list is the `Dictionary` in the form of this:

```
var source: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["value": 1, "text": "Text"]
```

The code above works well.

What I would like to get is this one:

```
var source: Dictionary<CustomKeySourceType, Any> = [.value: 1, .text: "Text"]
```

I attempted to build the solution like this one:

```
class KeySource {
    struct Key : Hashable, Equatable, RawRepresentable {
        var rawValue: String
        
        static let a = KeySource.Key(rawValue: "a")
        static let b = KeySource.Key(rawValue: "b")
        static let c = KeySource.Key(rawValue: "c")
        
        public init(_ rawValue: String){
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }

        public init(rawValue: String){
            self.rawValue = rawValue
        }
    }
}
...
var source: Dictionary<KeySource.Key, Any> = [.a: "a", .b: 1, .c: 3.33]
```

It compiles the code well, but rise an error in runtime:

```
var pbd = NSPasteboardItem(pasteboardPropertyList: source, ofType: .experimental)
```

`...*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not write property list with invalid format to the pasteboard.  The object contains non-property list types: __SwiftValue'...`

The explicit usage of the property list permitted types in the code fails with the same error message.

```
var source: Dictionary<KeySource.Key, Any> = [.a: NSString("a"), .b: NSNumber(1), .c: NSNumber(3.33)]
```

The `NSDictionary` substitution has no positive effect:

```
var source: NSDictionary = [KeySource.Key.a: NSString("a"), KeySource.Key.b: NSNumber(1), KeySource.Key.c: NSNumber(3.33)]
```

It produces the same runtime error.

The only way to make it work is to return to the `String` key type:

```
var source: Dictionary<String, Any> = [KeySource.Key.a.rawValue: NSString("a"), KeySource.Key.b.rawValue: NSNumber(1), KeySource.Key.c.rawValue: NSNumber(3.33)]
```

This solution needs to be lighter. I would like to have keys written briefly, like `.a`, `.b`, and `.c` form.

Please, help me to build right key source!

---

Xcode 12.4

Deployment target 10.15

Comment: @Cristik yes, experimental is added via extension `extension NSPasteboard.PasteboardType {
    static let experimental = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType("com.experimental")
}`

Comment: @Cristik I'm trying to avoid the `.rawValue` suffix in the key.

Comment: @Cristik I did not expect such functionality is the hardware dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a [property list compatible dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspropertylistserialization), otherwise you'll run into the exception/crash:

> A property list is itself an array or dictionary that contains only NSData, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, and NSNumber objects.

It's not difficult to create one, though, from your higher-level dictionary:

```swift
extension Dictionary where Key: RawRepresentable, Key.RawValue == String {
    var rawKeys: [Key.RawValue: Value] {
        reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key.rawValue] = $1.value }
    }
}
```

With the help of the above extension, you can convert your dictionary at the call site:

```
NSPasteboardItem(pasteboardPropertyList: source.rawKeys, ofType: .experimental)
```

Note that you still need to guarantee the validity of the values, in order to make sure they comply with the properly list allowed values.

---

If you need to also support the reverse - decoding the property list into a typed dictionary, you could implement an extension over `NSPasteboardItem` that will handle this:

```swift
extension NSPasteboardItem {
    func typedPropertyList<Key: RawRepresentable, Value>(forType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) -> [Key: Value]? where Key.RawValue == String {
        guard let dict = propertyList(forType: type) as? [String: Value] else { return nil }
        return dict.reduce(into: [:]) {
            if let wrappedKey = Key(rawValue: $1.key) {
                $0[wrappedKey] = $1.value
            }
            // ramaining question here is how to handle the failure path, we could
            // - just ignore it (like above), or,
            // - throw an exception, or
            // - return nil from the function
        }
    }
}
```

But if you do this, then you might want to also overload the `NSPasteboardItem` initializer, do you'd have a symmetry for these two operations:

```swift
extension NSPasteboardItem {
    convenience init?<Key: RawRepresentable, Value>(typedPropertyList: [Key: Value], ofType type: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType) where Key.RawValue == String {
        let rawKeys = typedPropertyList.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key.rawValue] = $1.value }
        self.init(pasteboardPropertyList: rawKeys, ofType: type)
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```swift
let source: [KeySource.Key: Any] = [.a: "a", .b: 1, .c: 3.33]
let pbd = NSPasteboardItem(typedPropertyList: source, ofType: .experimental)
let decoded: [KeySource.Key: Any]? = pbd?.typedPropertyList(forType: .experimental)

print(source, decoded)
```

Comment: First of all, I love your solution. It is unusual and elegant and needs only one call to the dictionary conversion. I will mark it the final if nothing better will appear. My concern is the inability to retrieve the results in a dot-member way. The call `let destination = pbd?.propertyList(forType: .experimental) as? Dictionary<KeySource.Key, Any>` will fail, but `let destination = pbd?.propertyList(forType: .experimental) as? Dictionary<String, Any>` will work. To extract the value, one need the construct: `let a = destination?[KeySource.Key.a.rawValue])`

Comment: Glad you liked it, @RubenKazumov, I've added a solution for the reverse operation too.

Comment: First of all, Thank you very much. Thank you for your time and knowledge. The particular solution probably will work, but I'm still amazed at its complexity. The solution is elegant but costs more than an option to pack the structured data into the `NSPropertyList` archiver or even `NSKeyedArchiver` as `Data` with all the objects and optional variables.

Comment: What do you mean by "costs more", @RubenKazumov? Do you means in terms on lines of code, or in terms of performance? As not sure the alternative of using `NSKeyedArchiver` will save either much code or performance, as you need to use a class instead of a Swift dictionary.

Comment: No offense @Cristik! I greatly appreciate your help! I selected terrible words to describe the situation on my project. I have to put a complex structure into the package. I prefer to continue directly with the `Data` type in the pasteboard. Initially, I tried to disassemble it into the property list for the transfer and assemble it back on the receiver.

Comment: No offense taken, @RubenKazumov. Yeah, if converting to data makes it easier for you to work with, then that's the way to go.